# How do I fit a “pocket door”?

Tags: pocket-door

What are the fitting options including using a preformed kit etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got to this site, hopefully can help you out.
http://video.bobvila.com/m/21319451/installing-a-pocket-door.htm